# using SELinux in yocto/poky

Tags: yocto, openembedded

Setup: I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and I am trying to build an image that includes some recipes from meta-selinux. I have tried to follow the READMEs and other help, but I am pretty stuck.

Here are the layers that I have:

```
drwxrwxr-x 19 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct  3 18:31 meta/
drwxrwxr-x 14 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct  3 22:49 meta-openembedded/
drwxrwxr-x  5 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct  3 18:31 meta-poky/
drwxrwxr-x  8 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct  3 18:31 meta-selftest/
drwxrwxr-x 16 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct  3 22:51 meta-selinux/
drwxrwxr-x  7 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct  3 18:31 meta-skeleton/
drwxrwxr-x 15 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct  3 22:19 meta-virtualization/
drwxrwxr-x  9 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct  3 18:31 meta-yocto-bsp/
drwxrwxr-x  7 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct  3 23:12 openembedded-core/
```

My bblayers.conf file has:

```
# POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION is increased each time  build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /yocto/poky/meta \
  /yocto/poky/meta-poky \
  /yocto/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  /yocto/poky/meta-selinux \
  "
```

When I try to do a `bitbake core-image-minimal` I get:

```
ERROR: Layer 'meta-python' depends on layer 'openembedded-layer', but this layer is not enabled in your configuration
```

So, I add that layer to bblayers.conf.

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /yocto/poky/meta \
  /yocto/poky/meta-poky \
  /yocto/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /yocto/poky/meta-trio \
  /yocto/poky/meta-openembedded \
  /yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  /yocto/poky/meta-selinux \
  "
```

and now I get

```
ERROR: Unable to start bitbake server
ERROR: Last 10 lines of server log for this session (/yocto/poky/build/bitbake-cookerdaemon.log):
    return bb.parse.handle(fn, data, include)
  File "/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/parse/__init__.py", line 117, in handle
    return h['handle'](fn, data, include)
  File "/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/parse/parse_py/ConfHandler.py", line 134, in handle
    abs_fn = resolve_file(fn, data)
  File "/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/parse/__init__.py", line 140, in resolve_file
    raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, "file %s not found" % fn)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] file /yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/conf/layer.conf not found
```

I am not sure where to go here. meta-openebedded was cloned from the repo, I did not remove the /conf/layer.conf that the error message mentions.

Comment: why the vote to close?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my `bblayers.conf`, I should have had

```
/yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
```

instead of

```
/yocto/poky/meta-openembedded \
```